# Connecting MySQL with JavaScript Calendar

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, calendar, connection

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbusername ='root';
$dbpassword ='';
$database ='mp19';

$link =mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','12345678');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('mp19', $link);

if (!$link)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $link);}

$sql="SELECT * FROM 3-33";
$rs=mysql_query_exec($link,$sql);

if (!$rs)
  {exit("Error in SQL");}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

These are the codes I generated for the connection of phpmysql and javascript calendar however there seems to be an error with the connection. Can someone help me check the codes  for this connection? :/

Also, I'm not sure how to incorporate these codes into the javascript calendar. The calendar is a hardcoded one which makes use of only javascript. My intention is to print the tasks stored in the phpmysql database in the javascript calendar but I'm totally lost. Can someone please advice me on how to continue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called `mysql_query_exec()` in php

use `mysql_query()` in this way

```
 mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )

mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

you are passing parameter wrongly

Comment: Yes, but I still get an error messsage. Do you have any sample codes?

Comment: Okay there is no more error message! :D But now how am I supposed to fetch the data and print it into the javascript calendar?

Comment: @Chandni: Dear Chandni  I would recommend to read some tutorial to fetch data from mysql via php. Thanks

Comment: I've read through countless tutorials but I'm still not sure on this. I am completely new in javascript. I just have to make use of this small portion for my project. That's why I'm very desperate, my project is due in 3 days and this calendar issue is all I have left. Please do advise, thanks.

Comment: @Chandni: Your recent question is updated check the code if works